# Why am I getting this generic, non-descript error in GDI+ when trying to save a PNG?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gdi+, png

I have a function that dynamically adds text to an image in a predesignated spot.  Originally I did it with jpegs, and it was working. I switched to PNG so the images would be better quality, as the original jpegs were kind of pixely.  Anyway, here is my code.  It executes down to the `oBitmap.Save()`, then dies with "A General Error Has Occurred in GDI+".

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.BufferOutput = True

    Try
        Dim oText As String = context.Server.HtmlDecode(context.Request.QueryString("t"))
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(oText) Then oText = "Placeholder"
        Dim oPType As String = context.Server.HtmlDecode(context.Request.QueryString("p"))
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(oPType) Then oPType = "none"

        Dim imgPath As String = ""
        Select Case oPType
            Case "c"
                imgPath = "img/banner_green.png"
            Case "m"
                imgPath = "img/banner_blue.png"
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception("no ptype")
        End Select

        Dim oBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(context.Server.MapPath(imgPath))
        Dim oGraphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap)
        Dim frontColorBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.White)
        Dim oFont As New Font(FONT_NAME, 30)


        Dim oInfo() As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders
        Dim oEncoderParams As New EncoderParameters(2)
        Dim xOffset As Single = Math.Round((oBitmap.Height - oFont.Height) / 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
        Dim oPoint As New PointF(275.0F, xOffset + 10)

        oEncoderParams.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L)
        oEncoderParams.Param(1) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth,8L)

        oGraphic.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
        oGraphic.DrawString(oText, oFont, frontColorBrush, oPoint)
        oBitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, oInfo(4), oEncoderParams)
        context.Response.Output.Write(oBitmap)

        oFont.Dispose()
        oGraphic.Dispose()
        oBitmap.Dispose()  
        context.Response.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The only changes I made to this from the jpeg version are:

- `context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"` changed to `"image/png"`
- changed base images (`img/banner_green.jpg`, `img/banner_blue.jpg`) to `.png`
- added the second encoding parameter specifying color depth
- changed `oInfo(1)` (jpeg) to `oInfo(4)` (png)

Are there more things I need to tweak to get this routine to properly generate the PNG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/tcurry/PNGsUsingGDIplus04222005063702AM/PNGsUsingGDIplus.aspx), Bitmap.Save requires a seekable stream to save as PNG, which HttpResponse.OutputStream isn't. You'll have to save the image into a MemoryStream first, and then copy the contents of it to Response.OutputStream, like:

```
Dim tempStream as New MemoryStream
oBitmap.Save(tempStream, ImageFormat.Png, oEncoderParams)
Response.OutputStream.Write(tempStream.ToArray(), 0, tempStream.Length)
```

Also note that the line

```
context.Response.Output.Write(oBitmap)
```

does something different then what you are probably expecting. `HttpResponse.Output` is a TextWriter, and the overload you use here, `TextWriter.Write(object)` will just call ToString on the object and write the results into the stream, what in this case results in writing "System.Drawing.Bitmap" to the output.

Comment: Even though Will's answer got me to find out what was wrong, your post outlines exactly what was wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're disposing of the bitmap before you're flushing the Response?  Try flipping that around.  Also, it looks like you're writing the bitmap to the stream twice.  I'm not sure why you're doing that.  Save the bitmap to the output stream or use the Write method of the Response object, but not both.

Comment: I dont think i am using the file system (ie saving the image to a directory?). Anyway, the script errors before getting to the dispose/flush lines but I will give it a whirl anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it still bombs at the save line. I am gonna go investigate this memorystream thing

Comment: Sorry, re-read through the code and changed my answer.  The two issues I'm seeing are the dispose then flush and the Save then Write.  Might be either one; what jpeg may deal with png may not.

Comment: from what I read online, the save portion writes the file info to the bitmap object, and the write displays it. I could be mistaken, but I will try muddling around some more

Comment: using the memory stream fixed the issue, I write the bitmap to the memory stream then write the memory stream to the response's output stream.   thanks!