# A generic error occurred in GDI+ (Works most of the time)

Tags: asp.net, gdi+

I have a asp.net handler that is called to generate dynamic images (Round icons indicating a fill level and different colors at different fill levels). The images are generated entirely in memory, and no image file is loaded during the process. This code works 99.9% of the time in production, however occasionally the handler quits working, throwing the exception below. An IIS reset will fix the problem. I am running windows server 2008 r2 standard with all the latest and greatest updates. I have include the relevant code below. Any ideas are appreciated.

I have already looked at dozens of articles and microsoft kb articles and almost all of them revolve around file and directory permissions. That does not seem applicable here.

Exception:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)

Code:

```
var fillPercentString = context.Request.QueryString["fillPercent"];
var iconSizeString = context.Request.QueryString["size"];
var colorString = context.Request.QueryString["fillColor"];
double fillPercent;
double.TryParse(fillPercentString, out fillPercent); //0.01 * (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fillPercentString) ? int.Parse(fillPercentString) : 0);
fillPercent = 0.01 * fillPercent;
var iconSize = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(iconSizeString) ? int.Parse(iconSizeString) : 16;
var iconWidth = iconSize;
var iconHeight = iconSize;
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorString);
if (iconSize < 0)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid size.");
}

if (fillPercent < 0 || fillPercent > 100)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid fill percentage.");
}

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(iconWidth + 1, iconHeight + 1))
using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
using (var backgroundFillBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
using (var fillBrush = new SolidBrush(color))
using (var outlinePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1f))
{
    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    var circleBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, iconWidth, iconHeight);

    // fill with transparent
    graphic.FillRectangle(backgroundFillBrush, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

    // fill a full circle
    graphic.FillEllipse(fillBrush, circleBounds);

    // draw a rectangle to clip out unneeded region
    if (fillPercent < 1.00)
    {
        graphic.FillRectangle(backgroundFillBrush, new RectangleF(0, 0, bitmap.Width, (int)((1 - fillPercent) * bitmap.Height)));
    }

    // draw the circle outline
    graphic.DrawEllipse(outlinePen, circleBounds);

    // finalize and save to cache
    bitmap.MakeTransparent(bitmap.GetPixel(1, 1));
    bitmap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    var returnBytes = memStream.ToArray();

    // write the image to the output stream
    if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(returnBytes, 0, returnBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting this generic, non-descript error in GDI+ when trying to save a PNG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511579/why-am-i-getting-this-generic-non-descript-error-in-gdi-when-trying-to-save-a)

Comment: Are you logging your values when you hit the error?  That is, what are your `fillPercent`, `Size` and `fillColor` values that are coming from `context` when it bombs?

Comment: Yes, here is a query string which was logged as an error. But once the errors start it happens for all values that I can tell. One page may have 300 images with varying levels. /TankFillIcon.ashx?fillPercent=25&size=24&fillColor=green